# Formatting book class display style

Tags: header-footer, book-design

I recently decide to change the report class to book class for my thesis. 
One noticeable difference is that at the top of the page, chapter name appears for book class.
Another noticeable difference is for every alternate page the page number appears at the top right instead of at the bottom of the page.

My goal is to make the chapter name disappears and make page number appears at the the bottom of the page for every single page. How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way: Use the `fancyhdr` package and kick out all `footers/headers` first with `\fancyhf{}` and then enable `\cfoot{\thepage}` for a bottom page number, centered. Use `\pagestyle{fancy}` then.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

% Dummy stuff
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `book` document class uses the `headings` page style for all pages except those that contain chapter headings (which use the `plain` page style). If I understand your requirements correctly, you want *all pages* to use the `plain` page style. This objective may be achieved by adding the following instruction to the document's preamble:

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: I should definitely go deeper into this `\ps@...` stuff... ;-)

Comment: That's cool ... I have no idea because I've never used the internal representation so far...

Comment: Why not simply do `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\begin{document}`? There's no chance the page style `headings` will be used unless explicitly requested.

Comment: @egreg - Excellent point. :-) I'll make the change.

Answer (score 2):

The package `scrlayer-scrpage` is another possibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```